# Read text file with arithmetic expressions line by line, calculate and in new text file write results

Tags: python

Text file looks like:

```
4-1
9-3
```

The new text file should look this when it is finalized:

```
4-1=3
9-3=6
```

I'm stuck in the beginning

```
handle = open('izrazi.txt', 'r')
read = handle.readlines() 
# getting the list here and I don't know how to calculate and my result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need to define and open the output file where to write your result, with the statement:

```
with open
```

and then iterate your lines from the input (`for line in read`), using `eval` to evaluate the operation from a string (`eval(line)`), and write it to the specified destination file with the concatenation of the read line and the obtained result (`output.write(line + "=" + str(res)+"\n")`)

```
handle = open('izrazi.txt', 'r')
read = handle.readlines() 
with open("output.txt", "w") as output:
    for line in read:
        res = eval(line.strip())
        output.write(line.strip()+"="+str(res)+"\n")
```

Comment: in the list from read  - first line looks like this 4-1\n ( maybe this newline is problem?)

Comment: I wrote what you said, but I get TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str , because read is list of strings with newline char

Comment: @Miki you can use .strip() method

Comment: @Miki check the update. The problem you got is because I forgot the str() to cast the int to string in the write method. Now it should be ok

Comment: Thanks Nikaido :) ! All the best !